# Testing database interactions

Tags: database, go, testing

I have an API that has a storage layer. It only does the database interactions and perform the CRUD operations. Now I want to test these functions.
In my path API/storage/ , I have different packages having functions to interact with different tables in same database. Tables A, B and C are in same database.

My file hierarchy goes like:

```
--api
  --storage
    --A
      --A.go
      --A_test.go
    --B
    --C
  --server
    --A
  --testData
    --A.sql
    --B.sql
```

In this way I want to test the whole storage layer using command

```
go test ./...
```

The approach I was following is that I have a function **RefreshTables** which first truncates the table, then fills it with a fixed test data that I have kept in testData folder. For truncating I do :

```
db.Exec("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;")
db.Exec("truncate " + table)
db.Exec("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;")
```

As go test runs test functions of different packages in parallel by default, multiple sql connections get created and **truncate** runs on some other connection while **set foreign key** runs on some other connection randomly from connection pool.

I am not able to pass my tests if run together but all tests pass if run alone or package wise.

If I do :

```
go test ./... -p 1
```

which makes test functions run one by one, all the tests pass.

I have also tried using a transaction for truncate and locking table before truncate.

I checked this article (https://medium.com/kongkow-it-medan/parallel-database-integration-test-on-go-application-8706b150ee2e), and he suggests making different databases in every test function and dropping that database after function ends. I think this will be very time taking.

It would be really helpful if someone suggest the best method for testing database interactions in Golang.

Comment: We are using one database per *package* (not per function). Functions in a package don't execute in parallel by default and can therefore share a database.

Comment: @Peter I have a situation where say A is brand and B is product. Product has a brand ID. To refresh product which is linked to brand using foreign key constraint, I need to have that brand first, so need to refresh brand then product in B. So this is where my method fails. Also I want to add parallel testing within package in future.

Comment: have you tried using test containers? you could just start seperate containers for each package

Comment: What kind of tests are you implementing? unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: For integration tests at work, my team has been using [testify suites](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite). That suite has a `SetupAllSuite` hook that is called and spins up a postgresql container before any test runs. In our `AfterTest` hook, we delete data from all tables. And, in our `TearDownAll` hook, we destroy the docker container.

I will look into open sourcing this mixin for testify suites, or, at least get you some sample code.

Comment: @JairoLozano I am doing integration testing. I need to run the tests on the CI/CD as well where it starts failing when multiple packages are there.

Comment: @steamrolla Thanks for suggesting a method. I will try to implement in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in integration testing, I'm not sure if mocking the data base drivers could work for you, but if so, I've been using [go-sqlmock](http://I%20don't%20have%20much%20experience%20on%20integration%20testing,%20I'm%20not%20sure%20if%20mocking%20the%20data%20base%20drivers%20could%20work%20for%20you,%20but%20if%20so,%20I've%20been%20using%20[this](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock)%20package%20for%20mocking%20sql%20databases%20and%20works%20like%20a%20charm.%20You%20could%20use%20it%20and%20literally%20have%20a%20separated%20database%20mock) package for mocking sql database results in unit tests and works like a charm. You could use it and literally have a separated "database engine" for each of your tests. It's a bit time consuming since you have to manually tell the mock what queries to expect and what to return but trust me, it's a good time investment.

As I said before, I'm not sure if using this strategy suits your case, because if you are interested in knowing how your application behaves in a "real database scenario", like verifying that registries are actually saved, then mocking the database results is kind of useless.

Comment: Thanks for your the suggestion but in my storage layer I want to test the real database interactions, checking if my queries are right and different data can be inserted into the database. I was thinking to use go-sqlmock but it wont remain an integration testing in that case and I would just be testing code part.